# Code First update a field with unloaded required navigation properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

This seems to be a pretty strange behavior of CodeFirst,

I got a table:

```
public string Name {get;set;}

[Required]
public virtual Table1 Table1 {get;set;}

[Required]
public virtual Table2 Table2 {get;set;}

[Required]
public virtual Table3 Table3 {get;set;}
```

Now if i get a row from the database like this:

```
var row = database.Include("Table1").First();

row.name = "New name";
row.Table1.name = "New name";

database.SaveChanges();
```

it will throw 2 errors:

```
Table2 : The Table2 field is required.

Table3 : The Table3 field is required.
```

Question is, Why does it validate those 2 non-loaded non-used references?

I would prefer not to load the ENTIRE entity, as some entities can have a lot of references, to just update 1 field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mark anything with `Required` attribute it is required to exist when saving changes. EF always validates whole entity during saving and navigation properties are handled in the same way as normal properties => null = exception. Validation also doesn't trigger lazy loading by design.

Your options are:

- Not using `Required` attribute be either

  - You can add non-nullable foreign key property for each navigation property
  - You can use fluent-api instead of data annotations
- Turn off EF validations